# Play sound when automated build fails

Tags: continuous-integration, nant, teamcity

We are using TeamCity v4 and NAnt for continuous integration builds on a server in our work area. We would like to have the build server play an mp3 or wav file when the build fails. Anyone has any ideas around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the [plugin that lets you use CCTray with TeamCity](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-11295?query=project%3A+TeamCity), then install and configure CCTray (on the build server itself if that's where you want the sound to play) and enable sound notifications. I found a [blog entry on how to do this](http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/using-cctray-with-jetbrains-teamcity/).

Alternately, you could [rig your build server up to a lava lamp](http://blog.coryfoy.com/2008/10/build-status-lamp-with-ruby-and-teamcity/) to display your build failure status :D

Edit: I've searched around and it seems like there's no simple way to do this using existing TeamCity build failue hooks. You could write a plugin to do it, but failing that it seems the above CCTray-based option is the best and cleanest.

Comment: Or you could use a robotic penguin to notify you of build failures. http://wiki.waltercedric.com/index.php?title=Tux_Droid_Plugin_For_TeamCity_Continuous_BuildServer
People come up with some weird stuff.

Comment: Hi imoatama

thanks for your answer. I've also come across CCTray with TeamCity, tried it but it failed. I think it's because we have TeamCity v4 and not v5, which does not have the Restful plugin. But that's another issue.

Thanks for you answer, it's been helpful and the lava lamp and robotic penguin are rather interesting.

Comment: Thanks for marking it as the answer even though I didn't solve the problem. I've just had a brainwave - you should easily be able to get what you want by installing Pidgin (or another IM client) on the server, turning on **its** sound notifications, and then using TeamCity's Jabber notifications (which I believe are supported in TC4). If TC is the server's only IM friend, the noise will only fire when it gets a message from the TC server :D

Comment: I thought I'd update this: the url to use for the report is `http://<tcurl>/guestAuth/app/rest/cctray/projects.xml`, not `http://<tcurl>/guestAuth/app/cctray-standalone/cctray/projects.xml`